# Passive & Active Voice confusion sentence construction after "In addition to"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Sorry for a not  very exact question, but I ask it because I would chose B or C according to the sentence meaning. If you don't do so, please choose your answer with explanation.

Phrase:

"In  addition to

A be banning
B banning
C ban
D being banned

for 12 months, he was ordered to take an extended driving test."

Comment: What is your question? Looking at the options A-D I presume the answer is chosen to complete the sentence in the passive voice. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer that would make sense would be D. Ban is a transitive verb, so it requires an object. A, B and C are in the active voice, so they would require an object, which is not provided in the sentence. You would need to use the passive voice, instead. Only D is passive.

http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-118-Transitive-and-Intransitive-Verbs.htm